# ns2 validate overall report: some tests failed

Tags: ns2

I have installed my ns-2.35 on my ubuntu 12.10

I got installation success info as below:

```
Ns-allinone package has been installed successfully.
Here are the installation places:
tcl8.5.10:  /opt/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/{bin,include,lib}
tk8.5.10:       /opt/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/{bin,include,lib}
otcl:       /opt/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14
tclcl:      /opt/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/tclcl-1.20
ns:     /opt/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/ns
nam:    /opt/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/nam-1.15/nam
xgraph: /opt/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/xgraph-12.2
gt-itm:   /opt/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/itm, edriver, sgb2alt, sgb2ns, sgb2comns, sgb2hierns
.
.
.
```

but when I executed the following command

```
sudo ./validate
```

There were error messages:

```
validate overall report: some tests failed:
 ./test-all-newreno ./test-all-tcpOptions ./test-all-tcpVariants ./test-all-aimd 
 ./test-all-frto ./test-all-quickstart ./test-all-manual-routing ./test-all-links
to re-run a specific test, cd tcl/test; ./test-all-TEST-NAME
```

and then I re-installed my ns2 and executed that command again

It showed even more failed tests:

```
validate overall report: some tests failed:
 ./test-all-newreno ./test-all-tcpOptions ./test-all-tcpVariants ./test-all-aimd 
 ./test-all-greis ./test-all-frto ./test-all-quickstart ./test-all-manual-routing 
 ./test-all-cbq ./test-all-intserv ./test-all-diffserv ./test-all-links 
 ./test-all-mpls ./test-all-satellite ./test-all-wpan ./test-all-srm ./test-all-plm
to re-run a specific test, cd tcl/test; ./test-all-TEST-NAME
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion? How can I fixed this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: There are some missing packages. Type the following command to install them.

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev xorg-dev libxmu-dev libperl4-corelibs-perl
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
http://simlz.blogspot.com/2014/12/install-ns2-use-ns-allinone-235-package.html

or you can access [NS2 Troubleshooting](http://nsnam.isi.edu/nsnam/index.php/Troubleshooting) for more detail about issues